# osgi bundle remains lazy and doesn't start automatically

Tags: java, osgi

I need my bundle to start automatically and load some dll but it stays in lazy state , thus the activator doesn't load my dll's .
is there a safe way to configure an osgi bundle to start and activate itself on startup?

Comment: It all depends on what container you are using, as each container has it's own way of defining auto-starts. Maybe, it'll help if you elaborate the question with those details.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click Project --> Run Configurations --> Bundles --> Select appropriate bundle --> Set Auto-Start property --> True

[image: For example]